# How to start ProjectLibre?

Tags: 13.10, startup-applications, project-management

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and `projectlibre 1.5.7-1`.

The application `ProjectLibre` shows up in the application list. But, when I click on it, nothing happens. I have tried to find information on the web; but, I am afraid to be limited by my Linux understanding.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as an administrator? I had the same problem. I was logged in as a standard user (no administrative privileges) and clicking ProjectLibre icon did nothing. When I logged in as Ubuntu administrator then everything worked.

I also figured out a way to make it start if logged in as non-admin user. Open the terminal (if you type terminal in the search the app icon will come up), type the following command:

```
/usr/bin/projectlibre
```

Comment: Note, in doing this you will also find out right away if your system does not have Java installed.  This turned out to be the real reason ProjectLibre wasn't opening for me, and the launcher (or Unity, maybe?) just wasn't sophisticated enough to inform me that it could not run the program without a JRE installed.  Silent failures are no fun.

Answer (score 0):

After execute: /usr/bin/projectlibre, the terminal Shown that does not install OpenJDK,.. I to proceed to install OpenJDK, and ready! .. ProjectLibre Start correctly.